# ¿Se puede generar script con datos de una base de datos grande SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, microsoft-sql

Sé que está pregunta es muy simple y básica pero es que dentro de poco tendré que duplicar la base de datos de producción de forma local en la empresa donde trabajo y tengo miedo de dañarla.

Mi duda es:
¿Puedo generar un script sql con los datos de un database **SQL Server** que constantemente se está usando sin correr el riesgo de dañarla o algo así?.

¿Y también puedo hacer back-up desde SQL Server Management Studio (MSSQL)?

Comment: [Acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16) te dejo el método mas efectivo. Con el asistente de SQL Server

Comment: Respuesta rápida a tus dos preguntas: Si. Ahora ¿por que no un backup/restore en vez del script?

Answer (score 0):

Si, puedes hacer un backup de un database mientras está siendo usado, aunque lo normal es hacer las copias de seguridad de forma automatizada por la madrugada u otro horario en el que se espera que haya menos actividad.

Puedes crear un script para generar un backup de las bases de datos y programar una tarea en el scheduler de Windows para que lo ejecute automáticamente cada cierto tiempo.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de script que puedes utilizar, lo comenté lo mejor que pude y añadí compresión de archivos que podría resultar útil si tus bases de datos son muy grandes. Modifica las variables en la parte "Configuracion del Database" con el nombre de tu servidor y de tus bases de datos.

```
@ECHO OFF

rem Directorio para guardar archivos de backup. NOTA: Debe terminar con un slash \
SET BAK_PATH=C:\DB_Backup\

rem Configuracion del Database
SET MSSQLSERVERNAME=.\SQLEXPRESS
SET MSSQLDATABASELIST=^
                 DB_1_NOMBRE^
                 DB_2_NOMBRE^
                 DB_3_NOMBRE
                 rem NOTA: No usar ^ en el ultimo elemento

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Cicla sobre las bases de datos
FOR %%i IN (%MSSQLDATABASELIST%) DO (
  SET DATABASENAME=%%i
  SET MyTime=%Time: =0%
  SET MyDate=%Date:~-4%.%Date:~3,2%.%Date:~0,2%.!MyTime:~0,2!.!MyTime:~3,2!.!MyTime:~6,2!
  SET FileName=!MyDate!_!DATABASENAME!.bak
  SET DEST_FILE=%BAK_PATH%!FileName!

  rem Crea el backup del Database
  sqlcmd -E -S %MSSQLSERVERNAME% -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [!DATABASENAME!] TO DISK = N'!DEST_FILE!' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'!DATABASENAME! backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
  rem NOTA: En caso de error "access is denied", solucionarlo en Services SQL properties - log on

  rem Comprime los archivos de backup
  7z a -tzip "!DEST_FILE!.zip" "!DEST_FILE!"
  rem NOTA: Instalar y añadir el directorio de la carpeta 7z en la variable de ambiente PATH

  rem Elimina los archivos de backup no comprimidos
  DEL "!DEST_FILE!"
)
```

'''